# Image Classification TensorFlow alternatives for minSDK 16?

Tags: android, tensorflow-lite, image-classification

I need to implement a way to use a .tflite file in Android for some offline image classification (and other use cases in the future). Currently, our app has a minSDK = 16, but the lowest requirement for an official TensorFlow lib is [level 19](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/android#min_sdk_version_of_tflite).

In case I have no choice, I'll use the tensorflow-lite-support lib, but going from 16 to 19 is a big jump for us (I know 19 isn't terrible, but the Support team isn't happy).

Is there an external library that would allow me to implement these features while maintaining the broadest device support (preferably as low as API 16)?

Comment: Requests for libraries are off topic here.  But push back on your version.  According to Google, 99.4% of all devices in the wild run 19 or later.  And the majority of those running older versions are in low income countries and aren't downloading software frequently.  You're spending a lot of time and effort to support what may well be 0 actual users.  You can up that to 21 and still only miss 2% of all devices, and all the way to 23 and only miss 6%.

Comment: Thanks for that info. Where would be the appropriate place to request for libraries?

Comment: Another site.  They're off topic as questions on stack overflow  (you can answer a question with a library suggestion, but not ask for a library that does X).